# Verify Divergence Theorem for Paraboloid

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $z=x^2+y^2$, and $0\leq z \leq 4$ and let a) $F=[x,y,2z]$ b) $F=[x,y,3z]$. Verifying Divergece theorem gives for the volum integral using a)  $\nabla \cdot F=4$  and b) $\nabla \cdot F=5$ and using
$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^2 \int_{r^2}^4 (\nabla \cdot F) r dz dr d\theta$ gives 
a) $32 \pi$ and b) $40 \pi$.

Surface integral for the top of paraboloide is for a) $32 \pi$  b) $48 \pi$ and for the side of the paraboliode gives for a) $0$ and b) $-8 \pi$ where we use normal vector for the side of paraboloid $(2r^2 \cos \theta , 2r^2 \sin \theta , -r)$ My question is if the direction of the unity vector is correct now?

This gives correct answer for part b) to get $48 \pi - 8 \pi = 40 \pi$ as well.

Remember the unity normal vector used for the top is [0,0,1] and for side is $\frac{[-2r^2 cos \theta, -2r^2\sin \theta, r]}{ r \sqrt{4r^2+1}} $ for this transformation the Jacobi is $ r \sqrt{4r^2+1} $ and Jacobi and the length of unity normal vector are simplified (deleted).  Here we should choose the unity normal vector outward, so it would be: $\frac{[2r^2 cos \theta, 2r^2\sin \theta, -r]}{ r \sqrt{4r^2+1}} $

Comment: The divergence $5$ in part b), isn't it? The paraboloid must have *outward*-pointing normal vector (where "outward" means *away from the region on the inside*), so the $z$-coordinate must be negative. This is true, obviously, in both part a) and part b). But, at any rate, aren't you subtracting in the wrong direction? You subtract the flux across the top disk *from* the triple integral of the divergence to obtain the flux across the paraboloid.

Comment: Thank you for you comments. Yes $\nabla \cdot F= 5$for part b). Is this unity normalvecktor pointing innward?  $\frac{[-2r^2 cos \theta, -2r^2\sin \theta, r]}{ r \sqrt{4r^2+1}} $

Comment: Yes. Draw a picture!